# How Can I match Id from another table

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have two Tables First Table is series Table second is a series_type Table and I want to match series_id column in the series_type Table but in a series_type column i have multiple values so how can I  match the column id in the series_type Table?

I have two table
1st Table is storage_series

```
series_id | series_name
   1     | abc
   2     | def
   3     | ghi
   4     | ijk
         |
```

2nd Table is Storage_Type

```
storage_type_id| name   | series_id
_______________|________|___________________
   1          | JBOD   | 1,4,2,3
   2          | RAID5  | 1,2
   3          | RAID6  | 1,3
   4          | DVD    | 4
```

Comment: expected output, & your so far code, please

Comment: [list of doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6baa6fd0902b4c244f28f3c47a16aab7)**

```
SELECT storage_type_id,names,ser_id,group_concat(series_name) value
FROM   t1 join t2  
on  FIND_IN_SET(
       t1.series_id, t2.ser_id)
       group by storage_type_id,names,ser_id
```

OUTPUT:

```
storage_type_id names   ser_id   value
1               JBOD    1,4,2,3  abc,def,ghi,ijk
2               RAID5   1,2      abc,def
3               RAID6   1,3      abc,ghi
4               DVD     4        ijk
```